# Extensions to Generic classes without specifying T

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Generic class I want to extend externally.

If I were within the class of `MyGenericClass<T>`, I could simply define a method like

```
public MyReturnType MyMethod() 
{ 
    MyReturnType m; 
    //some code
    return m;
}
```

Which can then be called by an instance, as usual, with `myGenericClass.MyMethod();`

However, I want to add this function externally using extensions.

The following does not compile:

```
public static MyReturnType MyMethod(this MyGenericClass<T> mgc)
{
    MyReturnType m; 
    //some code
    return m;
}
```

because type T cannot be inferred.

The following does compile:

```
public static MyReturnType MyMethod<T>(this MyGenericClass<T> mgc)
{
    MyReturnType m; 
    //some code
    return m;
}
```

However, this requires that I type `myGenericClass.MyMethod<MyT>();` and worse, there is no constraint on "T" in MyMethod to be the same as the "T" in MyGenericClass - the two generics are independent (and rely on the user using the same type for both class and function).

How do I declare this properly?

Thanks
Haighstrom

Comment: Yes the T is the same T, and if you want a clause, simply add 'where T : IComparable’ to the method signature.

Comment: It is the same T. Did you try testing it? If you make an object of MyGenericClass<int> - you cannot call MyMethod<string> on it - compilation error right there.

Comment: `myGenericClass` will have to be concrete ex (`MyGenericClass<Boolean>`) so when you have an object of that the type T is already known. `myGenericClass.MyMethod();` will be implied

Comment: You're all right, and I was being an idiot. When I changed to it to 'Method<T>(this Class<T> c)' the static declaration got lost somehow so I thought it wasn't working. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last definition is the correct one. The fact that you use `T` in both the method declaration and the type parameter means that the type with be constrained to be the same in both cases (meaning you can't cross the types).